On the Representation Of Quadratic form
I have been learning about quadratic forms recently and came across the following statement, which I am unable to prove. Suppose $X$ is a rational quadratic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$, and let $Q$ be the quadratic form defining $X$. Then, with respect to some rational basis, $Q$ can be written in the following form:
$$
Q(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 2x_1 x_{n+1} + \tilde{Q}(x_2, \dots, x_n).
$$
Since quadratic forms have a matrix representation, I was trying to find a basis in which $Q$ takes the above form in a specific example. However, I am unsure how to prove this in general — that is, how to construct a basis with respect to which $Q$ has the desired form.
Additionally, can a similar decomposition be done for higher-order forms, such as cubic forms? Since there is no matrix representation in these cases, can something similar be said for higher-order forms?Any help is very much appreciated. This has been used in a paper https://people.brandeis.edu/~kleinboc/Pub/kdsjournal.pdf
in the first line of the page 465.

suggest you give a link to a reference.  Meanwhile, what happens   for the smallest values of $n?$  Might make sense for $n=1,$  although I am a bit unsure about the bounds...Can you write out the correct relation?

This is used in a paper. May be I am giving the link of the paper.
